# Bulma installation on laravel project failed on laravel 7

Tags: bulma, laravel-7

Just try to install Bulma on a fresh new laravel project and get this error,
my steps is : 
Install this preset via composer require laravel-frontend-presets/bulma. No need to register the service provider. Laravel 5.5 & up can auto detect the package.
Use php artisan ui bulma for basic Bulma preset
npm install
npm run dev

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/index.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
8 │ @import "node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all"
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  resources/sass/bulma.sass 8:9
```

Someone know how fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

At first view bulma is not compatible with laravel 7,
So if you want to use it you have this repo that give you a solution :
https://github.com/Norbertho/laravel-7-bulma-frontend-preset